# Elixir, test supervisor restart policy

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I am writing an OTP application with a supervisor tree.

The main supervisor supervise two process a worker, QueueAddress, and another supervisor, QueueManager, with strategy `one_for_one`

QueueManager supervise a bunch of little Queues, with strategy `simple_one_for_one`, every time a new queue is started, its basic information are saved into the QueueAddress.

If a queue is killed, it is restarted correctly.

Now I want to test what happen if the supervisor QueueManager is killed.

However if a simply send a message `Process.exit(QueueManager, :normal)`, or `Process.exit(QueueManager, :shutdown)` nothing happen, the PID of the QueueManager doesn't change nor the PIDs of the little queue that are supervised.

If I send a message `Process.exit(QueueManager, :kill)` the whole application gets down.

How can I test, what happen if QueueManager gets killed ?

Below the image of the OTP tree, I want to kill `Elixir.QueueManager`

[image: The OTP tree]

Comment: Isn't Process.exit/2 working only with pids? You can try doing something like name |> Process.whereis |> Process.exit(:normal)

Answer (score 2):

It was pretty simple...

If you want to terminate the supervisor A, supervised by B you could do something like:

`Supervisor.terminate_child B, A`

If you want to bring back to life the supervisor A, still supervised by B you can do:

`Supervisor.restart_child B, A`